# Deploying a TypeScript WebRole with VS 2015 Update 1

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment

I installed VS 2015 Update 1 two days ago and since then I've not been able to deploy (or package) my TypeScript WebRole.

Basically, it appears that when MSBUILD is trying to process the .TS files if fails. The error it gets is "The given path's format is not supported"

The paths would look like:
Error  Unable to copy file "E:\Temp\AzureCloudService1\WebRole1\app\test1.js" to "E:\Temp\AzureCloudService1\AzureCloudService1\obj\Release\WebRole1\E:\Temp\AzureCloudService1\WebRole1\app\test1.js". The given path's format is not supported. AzureCloudService1 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets 2787

Error  Unable to copy file "E:\Temp\AzureCloudService1\WebRole1\app\test1.js.map" to "E:\Temp\AzureCloudService1\AzureCloudService1\obj\Release\WebRole1\E:\Temp\AzureCloudService1\WebRole1\app\test1.js.map". The given path's format is not supported. AzureCloudService1 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets 2787

The errors above is on a brand new solution I created to test the problem. I created an Azure Cloud Service with a WebAPI webrole. To the WebAPI, I added a TypeScript file. If I try to package (or deploy) the Azure Cloud Service I get the messages above.

If instead I include the JavaScript generated by TypeScript and remove the .TS file, then the build works fine.

I have uninstalled and re-installed VS, but at this stage any installation insists in adding Update 1 so I can't get back to an useful working environment.

Luckily, I have an old desktop without the Update 1 installed and I can use that one for deployment. But of course, that's not ideal.

Thanks in advance for any help.